# Sending Thumbprint of a Key Vault Certificate to Service Bus topic through Azure Portal configuration

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-keyvault, azureportal, azure-servicebus-topics

I have come across this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions which does the following:

1.Create a Service Bus namespace, using the Azure portal.
2.Create a Service Bus topic, using the Azure portal.
3.Create a Service Bus subscription to that topic, using the Azure portal.
4.Write a .NET Core console application to send a set of messages to the topic.
5.Write a .NET Core console application to receive those messages from the subscription.

I have a Azure Key Vault and want to send a message to the topic as mentioned in Step #4 above. Basically, I want to send the Thumbprint corresponding to a Key Vault Certificate to the topic as in Step #4 whenever a new Key Vault Certificate gets generated. Is that possible to be configured in the Azure portal?

I want to update a set of data files with the thumbprint corresponding to the Key Vault Certificate as soon as a new Certificate gets generated in Azure Key Vault. The application in Step #5 could serve that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the discussion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/795951/sending-thumbprint-of-a-key-vault-certificate-to-s.html).

As per your requirement, you should use Azure Event Grid trigger to monitor your key vault and you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-overview) for more details. The available events for the key vault are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#available-event-types). You can leverage the Microsoft.KeyVault.KeyNewVersionCreated (Triggered when a new key or new key version is created.) or Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNewVersionCreated (Triggered when a new secret or new secret version is created.) as per your requirement.

**Workflow:**

There is no out of box feature that will send the thumbprint when the event is triggered so either at your application end you need to make a REST call to query the azure key vault resource to get the thumbprint or offload this functionality to the azure function app where you write the logic to make a REST call to get the thumbprint from key valut.

Key Valut --> Event Grid --> Service Bus --> Your application

Key Valut --> Event Grid --> function app (that will get the thumbprint and pass it as as message content while sending the message) --> Service Bus --> Your application